# Difference between MERGE and CREATE in Cypher Neo4j

Tags: javascript, neo4j

I'm just importing some stuff from .csv file to Neo4j. I've always used `MERGE` to create a node, but now, when trying to import from .csv, some of data is null, e.g. column `address`. When I'm doing `MERGE` instead of `CREATE` it gives an error, but when I do `CREATE` it works fine. The only difference I know between `MERGE` and `CREATE` is that if the node already exists, `MERGE` doesn't make a new one.

My query:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM '<path>' as line
                   CREATE (a: Address
                   {
                   address: line.address,
                   postalCode: toInteger(line.postalCode),
                   town: line.town,
                   municipalityNr: toInteger(line.municipalityNr),
                   municipality: line.municipality,
                   countryCode: line.countryCode,
                   country: line.country
                  
                   })
                    RETURN a.address
```

Comment: Could you please also share the query with `MERGE` and the error it produces?

Comment: It's the same query but instead of CREATE there is MERGE.

Answer (score 2):

When doing a `MERGE`, Neo4j expects a value that it can merge on. `MERGE` using a null will always result in an error.

In general, this is the approach:

Only `MERGE` on properties that are relevant to finding a unique node. So for instance, if you want to `MERGE` cars, the licence plate would be the property to use.
Make sure you have a `CONSTRAINT` for the property you `MERGE` on. This will help speed up the import.
To avoid nulls in the `MERGE`, you can use `COALESCE()`.
After the `MERGE`, you can `SET` the other properties, which may have nulls.

```
MERGE {c:Car {licensePlate: COALESCE(line.licensePlate,'Unknown') })
SET c.color = line.color,
    c.someproperty = line.someproperty
```

At the end of the run, you will find a single `:Car` node with `licensePlate:'Unknown'`

Answer (score 0):

Agree with Graphileon.

There is a trap you should avoid. You also want to avoid properties that may vary within a data set. For instance the same person has a birth date in different formats (e.,g, 5/16/85, 05/16/1985), you would add duplicate nodes if birth date was part of the merge criteria. To avoid this, you can do the merge without the date and then, in a subsequent step, add the property ... of course, only the last such effort would endure.

You can check to see that there are no duplicate nodes. In the example given, if your sure the name is unique, or license number of the car:

```
match (p:Person) return p.name, count(*) as ct order by ct desc
```